# Por que mi html no lee el los márgenes de mi css?

Tags: html, css, margin

Todo lo que es colores, font-size y color me lo toma, pero por alguna razón los margin no. Nunca antes me había pasado y ya llevo horas intentando solucionarlo. Acá el código HTML resumido

```css
.conenedor {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <nav class="navprin" class="contenedor">
        <a href="nosotros.html">Inicio</a>
        <a href="nosotros.html">Sobre mi</a>
        <a href="nosotros.html">Clientes</a>
        <a href="nosotros.html">Contacto</a>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Por alguna razón si hago agrego el style desde el HTML si me funciona:

```html
<body>
 <nav class="navprin" class="contenedor" style="width: 50%; margin-top: 0; margin-right: auto; margin-bottom: 10%; margin-left: auto;">
        <a href="nosotros.html">Inicio</a>
        <a href="nosotros.html">Sobre mi</a>
        <a href="nosotros.html">Clientes</a>
        <a href="nosotros.html">Contacto</a>
    </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: ¿tienes definidos los elementos `a` con `display: inline-block;`?

Comment: Por si ocurre en el código, hay un error en el nombre de la clase en el CSS, escribiste `.conenedor` en lugar de `.contenedor`

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Edité tu pregunta para hacer uso de los _snippets_, que permiten _ejecutar_ para ver el resultado de fragmentos html/css/javascript directamente en la pregunta/respuesta. Te sugiero darle clic al link para editar para ver cómo se hace (hay un botón que te abre un diálogo para insertar el código y probarlo mientras escribes la pregunta).

Answer (score 2):

Hay dos errores en tu código:

1. El nombre de la clase no coincide (se llama **conenedor** –sin la T– en el CSS y **contenedor** en el HTML). Estos nombres deben coincidir y debes ser cuidadoso, pues es común que se cometa algún error tipográfico u ortográfico que rompa las cosas.
2. Cuando quieres aplicar varias clases a un elemento, utilizas un solo atributo `class` y las listas todas, separadas por espacios. Tu tienes 2 atributos "class", lo cual [es un error](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#parse-error-duplicate-attribute) y puede provocar comportamientos indefinidos en distintos navegadores, aunque lo estándar es que se [ignore el segundo atributo](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/parsing.html#attribute-name-state).

Corrigiendo estos dos errores, nos quedaría algo como:

```css
.contenedor {
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 0;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 10%;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<body>
 <nav class="navprin contenedor">
        <a href="nosotros.html">Inicio</a>
        <a href="nosotros.html">Sobre mi</a>
        <a href="nosotros.html">Clientes</a>
        <a href="nosotros.html">Contacto</a>
    </nav>
</body>
```